# guardar errores en variable al hacer un save en mongodb con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

En una ruta usando nodejs con express y mongodb estoy declarando una variable llamada `errors` de tipo objeto donde intento guardar los errores que sucedan en un map dentro del cual se hace un save en base de datos. El problema es que cuando voy a revisar la variable errors despues de haber hecho el map con un console log en una condicional `if(errors)` la variable errors esta vacia. Sin embargo si hago un console log dentro del map si me muestra el error correctamente.
Entonces eso llevo a pensar que puede ser que al momento del console log del condicional de abajo quiza el map no se ha hecho, lo cual me parece raro considerando que la funcion saveLanguages es sincrona.

```js
exports.start = async (req, res) => {

    function saveLanguajes() {
        try{
            let errors = {};
            Object.keys(languages).map(function (key, index) {  

                let languageObject = {
                    abbreviation: key,
                    name: languages[key].name,
                    native_name: languages[key].nativeName
                };

                language = new Language(languageObject);

                language.save({ runValidators: true }, async (err, languageDB) => {
                    if(err){
                        errors[key] = [];
                        if(err.errors.hasOwnProperty('abbreviation')){
                            errors[key].push(err.errors.abbreviation.properties.message);
                        } else if(err.errors.hasOwnProperty('name')){
                            errors[key].push(err.errors.name.properties.message);
                        } else if(err.errors.hasOwnProperty('native_name')){
                            errors[key].push(err.errors.native_name.properties.message);
                            console.log(errors);
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            });
            if(errors){
                console.log(errors);
                return res.status(400).json({ ok: false, errors: errors });
            }else{
                return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
            }
        }catch(errors){
            console.log(errors);
            return res.status(400).json({ ok: false, errors });
        }
    }

    await saveLanguajes();
    
}
```

Comment: El primer comentario que quiero hacer es que para comprobar si `errors` contiene algún error, deberías hacer algo como: `Object.keys(errors).lenght != 0`, ya que errors es un objeto. Deberías de tener en cuenta que el código del `if` se va a ejecutar antes de que acabe el map. Prueba a encerrar la comprobación de existencia de errores dentro de un setTimeout().

Comment: @H.Díaz, ese no es el problema, el problema es de asincronía, puedes leer mi respuesta al respecto. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema (siempre lo es), es de asincronía. El uso de la palabra [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) en una función no convierte el código dentro de la misma mágicamente en código síncrono. Por lo tanto, tu afirmación:

> *... lo cual me parece raro considerando que la función `saveLanguages` es sincrona.*

es incorrecta.

Otro problema que veo, es que intentas hacer múltiples llamadas a la Base de Datos para salvar diferentes documentos de una lista. Cosa que puedes hacer con una sola llamada, haciendo el proceso más eficiente en ese aspecto.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es lograr una operación de inserción de múltiples documentos en una sola llamada a la base de datos, para ello (asumiendo que usas [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)), lo ideal es usar el método [`insertMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) del modelo de datos (en este caso el modelo se llama *Language*).

En tu código no muestras de dónde sacas la variable `languages`, sólo se ve que haces:

```js
Object.keys(languages).map(function (key, index) { // <- ¿dónde declaras languages?
```

Asumo que `languages` es una variable de un ámbito superior (mala práctica), por lo tanto, vamos a refactorizar un poco para hacer las cosas con más cuidado. Vamos a redefinir la función `saveLanguages()` de tal forma que reciba como parámetro la variable `languages` que usas dentro de la misma:

```js
function saveLanguages(languages) { ... }
```

Ahora que ya sabemos de donde sale la variable, podemos crear una lista a partir de esta variable, para ello usaremos el método `map` que ya has aplicado pero el mismo nos devolverá una lista de documentos, es decir, no llamaremos al método `save()` de cada documento durante el proceso de mapeo.

El código puede verse algo así:

```js
function saveLanguages(languages) {
  let documentos = Object.keys(languages).map( key => {
    return new Language({
      abbreviation: key,
      name: languages[key].name,
      native_name: languages[key].nativeName
    });
  });
  // ...
}
```

Como se observa, estamos devolviendo un documento de tipo *Language* por cada elemento de la lista de claves generada a partir del objeto `languages`. La lista de todos esos documentos se almacena en `documentos`.

Ahora usaremos el método `insertMany()` de Mongoose, para insertar (crear) todos los documentos de la lista en la Base de Datos.

Una de las preocupaciones o dudas frecuentes al momento de usar este método, es sobre la validación de los datos. Si tienes bien definido tu esquema de datos, Mongoose se encargará de realizar las validaciones necesarias antes de enviar los datos a MongoDB. De la documentación se tiene: (traducción propia)

> Mongoose siempre valida cada documento antes de enviar (el comando) `insertMany` a MongoDB. De modo que si un documento tiene un error de validación, ningún documento será salvado, a menos que se establezca la opción `ordered` a `false`.
>
> Esta función no implementa el *middleware* `save`.
>
> Esta función implementa el siguiente *middleware*:
>
> - `insertMany`

Entonces, si tenemos alguna función [*middleware*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) (`pre` o `post`) para `save()` sería necesario escribir una para `insertMany` si vamos a usar este método. Ojo con esto.

Dicho esto, ahora debemos decidir si usaremos la opción `ordered` establecida en `true` (por defecto) o en `false`. Nuevamente, de la documentación se tiene: (traducción propia)

> - [options.ordered «Boolean» = true] si es `true`, fallará en el primer error encontrado. Si es `false`, insertará todos los documentos que pueda y reportará los errores luego.

Dependiendo de lo que deseamos hacer, podemos pedir que no inserte ningún documento si alguno falla la validación, por lo cual por los momentos dejaremos esta opción por defecto.

El código puede verse ahora así:

```js
function saveLanguages(languages) {
  let documentos = Object.keys(languages).map( key => {
    return new Language({
      abbreviation: key,
      name: languages[key].name,
      native_name: languages[key].nativeName
    });
  });
  Language.insertMany(documents, (error, insertedLanguages) => {
    if(error) {
      // si hubo algún error, el primero será reflejado aquí y no se insertará
      // ningún documento en DB
      console.log(error.message);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: true,
        message: error.message // <- validation error
      });
    }
    // si no hubo error, todos los documentos fueron insertados en DB
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Todos los registros creados correctamnete',
      languages: insertedLanguages
    });
  });
}
```

Supongamos que deseamos insertar tantos documentos como sea posible, entonces debemos establecer la opción `ordered` a `false`, pero, ¿cómo obtenemos los errores de los documentos que no fueron insertados?. Para ello usaremos la opción `ordered` establecida a `false` y añadiremos la opción `rawResult` establecida a `true` también, lo que hará que se nos devuelva un objeto con el resultado de MongoDB donde podremos encontrar un objeto llamado `mongoose` que contendrá los errores en un campo llamado `validationErrors`:

```js
Language.insertMany(documents, { ordered: false, rawResult: true }, result => {
  console.log(result);
  // en result.ops se encuentra la lista de documentos insertados.
  let insertados = result.ops && result.ops.length && [ ...results.ops ];
  console.log(resultados);
  let errores = result.mongoose && result.mongoose.validationErrors.length && [ ...result.mongoose.validationErrors ];
  console.log(errores);
  
  // lógica de envío del resultado al cliente
  }
});
```

Como puedes observar, usar las opciones `ordered` y `rawResult` nos resulta bastante conveniente a la hora de depurar el resultado de la operación. El objeto `result` devuelto podría verse parecido al siguiente (ejemplo para 3 documentos, donde 2 fueron insertados y el tercero no superó la validación):

```js
{
  result: { ok: 1, n: 2 },
  ops: [
    {
      _id: 5fa401455e7aec4f4025e4e5,
      abbreviation: 'sp',
      name: 'Spanish',
      native_name: 'Español',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 5fa401455e7aec4f4025e4e6,
      abbreviation: 'ca',
      name: 'Catalan',
      native_name: 'Catalàn',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  insertedCount: 2,
  insertedIds: { '0': 5fa401455e7aec4f4025e4e5, '1': 5fa401455e7aec4f4025e4e6 },
  mongoose: { validationErrors: [ [Error] ] }
}
```

De aquí es fácil obtener la lista de elementos que no fueron insertados, comparando los valores de `insertedIds` con los `_id`'s de la lista de documentos original.

**`async` o no `async`, esa es la pregunta**

En tu código se ve que intentas usar funciones tipo `async`:

```js
exports.start = async (req, res) => { // <- declaración async
// ...
language.save({ runValidators: true }, async (err, languageDB) => { // declaración async
```

Las funciones tipo `async` son un tipo de función que te permite utilizar el operador [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await), para que el código dentro de la función `async` se comporte semánticamente como un código síncrono (aunque siga siendo asíncrono).

Por ejemplo:

```js
function async miProceso(argumento) {
  try {
    // ... operaciones previas con argumento
    let resultado = await ProcesoAsíncrono(argumentoProcesado);
    console.log(resultado);
    // ... operaciones con resultado
    return resultadoProcesado;
  }
  catch(error) {
    // manejo del error
  }
}
```

Como se puede observar, se usa `await` para esperar que la función `ProcesoAsíncrono()` devuelva un resultado en algún momento futuro, por lo tanto, semánticamente hablando, cuando se ejecuta la siguiente linea (`console.log`) la variable resultado tiene efectivamente algún valor. Si ocurriese un error durante la ejecución de `ProcesoAsíncrono()`, el mismo sería capturado por el bloque `catch`.

Ahora, para que esto funcione, `ProcesoAsíncrono()` debe devolver una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) o debe retornar un objeto `thenable` o cualquier otro valor por cual haya que esperar, de lo contrario no podemos usar esta estructura.

Las `Queries` de Mongoose tienen  la particularidad de que pueden devolver una Promesa si no se usa una función `callback` como argumento o devuelven `undefined` si usamos un `callback`.

Por último, toda función tipo `async` devuelve una Promesa, por lo tanto no podemos obtener el resultado directamente por asignación, sino a través de `await` o a través del método `then()`:

```js
let miResultado = miProceso(miArgumento);
console.log(miResultado); // <- undefined

// ...
try {
  let miResultado = await miProceso(miArgumento);
  console.log(miResultado); // <- valor devuelto por miProceso
} catch(e) {
  // manejo de error de miProceso
}

// ...
miProceso(miArgumento)
.then(miResultado => {
  // el resultado de miProceso vive sólo aquí dentro
})
.catch(error => {
  // manejo de error
});
```

En el caso de tu pregunta, no veo necesidad de usar `async / await` ya que tu función *middleware* retorna directamente un resultado al cliente, finalizando así el proceso `solicitud/respuesta`.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te permita resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias, super completa tu respuesta, estoy empezando con nodejs y aun no se las mejores practicas ni las maneras correctas de hacer las cosas. Esto funciono perfectamente.